# How to assign values of list inside list to values of another list inside list (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have two lists inisde lists like this:

```
lst1 =[['a','b'],['c']]
lst2 =[['dropnulls','regex']]
```

where lst1 has the column names of the data frame and the lst2 has the process of what has to do if dropnulls then it should drop nulls if regex then drop all except numeric values. Now if
`lst1 =['a','b','c'] and if lst2 =['dropnulls','regex']` then we can do like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
data = [['abc123','abc23','123'],[np.nan,'123',np.nan],['bc123','qwe','abc'],['ABC@*&123',np.nan,'abc']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df)
 a      b    c
0     abc123  abc23  123
1        NaN    123  NaN
2      bc123    qwe  abc
3  ABC@*&123    NaN  abc

lst1 =['c','a','b'] 
lst2 =['regex']
for l in lst1:
    if 'dropnulls' in lst2:
        print(df[l].dropna())
    if 'regex' in lst2:
        print(df[df[l].str.contains(r'^\d+$', na=True)])

Then we get :
for regex:
 a      b    c
0  abc123  abc23  123
1     NaN    123  NaN
for dropnulls:
0    123
2    abc
3    abc
Name: c, dtype: object
0       abc123
2        bc123
3    ABC@*&123
Name: a, dtype: object
0    abc23
1      123
2      qwe
Name: b, dtype: object
```

But when lists like this is given `lst1 =[['a','b'],['c']],lst2 =[['dropnulls','regex']`]. It should do according to the position of the values in the lists like:

`lst1[0] is ['a','b']` this column has to go only for the method at `index[0]` for list inside list that is those both column should go to `dropnulls` and the `['c']` where `index[1]` has to go to `index[1]` list inside list that is `regex`.

eg:

```
lstl[0] = lst2(list[0])
lst1[1]=lst2(list[1])
```

It has to go like this into a loop. we can hardcode it and do but what if the methods are written in other order how can we do it?
Is there any method where we can send the column names and appropriate method for the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but you have a problem with adjusting items from both lists to correlate.

You can do this like that:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
data = [['abc123','abc23','123'],[np.nan,'123',np.nan],['bc123','qwe','abc'],['ABC@*&123',np.nan,'abc']]
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b','c'])
print(df)
lst1 =[['a','b'],['c']]
lst2 =[['dropnulls','regex']]

functions = {
    'dropnulls': lambda x: df[x].dropna(),
    'regex': lambda x: df[df[x].str.contains(r'^\d+$', na=True)]
}

for index, internal_list in enumerate(lst1):
    for col in internal_list:
        operation = lst2[0][index]
        function = functions[operation]
        print(function(col))
```

The top part is the same as your program. Next, I defined a dictionary, to access specific functions easily, using lambda syntax. After that, you need to iterate through the first list, saving list index, and then iterate over the nested list inside, to do your actions on each column.

Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes, almost but instead of doing it on each column. can we pass columns like a,b to dropnulls and column c to regex?